# Options to Bring Forward/ to Front/ etc are grayed out in Preview

Tags: preview

An *oval annotation* was added to a screenshot in `Preview`:

[image]

As can be seen the options to change the layers from the right-click/context menu popup are disabled. What is needed to make them available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it!  The option is *hidden in the *Colors* dialog*:

Note the `Opacity` slider !

[image]

And here is the result

[image]

Comment: I'm still not clear what the solution was here. Can you edit your answer to explain? The opacity of the selected object in your original screenshot clearly isn't 4%, so what's going on?

Comment: I had apparently not "saved" the updated screenshot: it's there now